# Ideal generated by an ideal and an element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ a commutative ring with unity. Let $a\notin I$ and we consider the ideal $(I,a)$. I have already shown that $$(I,a)=\big\{i+ra\;|\;i\in I, r\in R\big\}.$$

Why, $(I,a)=(I\cup(a))$?
I know that $(I,a)$ is the smallest ideal that contains $I$ and $a$, but how do you say that he coincides with $(I\cup (a))$?

Thanks!

Comment: Why $I \color{red}{\cup} (a)$? Example, $R = \mathbb Z$, $a = 4, I = 6\mathbb Z$, then $I \cup (4) = 4\mathbb Z \cup 6 \mathbb Z$, but $J=(I, a) = 2\mathbb Z$: $4, 6 \in J\implies 6-4 = 2\in J$, hence $(2)\subseteq J$. Since $\mathbb Z$ is a PID, $J = (2)$. Then $10 \in J$, but $10 \notin 4\mathbb Z \cup 6\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I was wrong to write, $(I,a)=(I\cup (a))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal $(I\cup(a))$ is the smallest ideal containing $I$ and $(a)$; in particular it contains $I$ and $a$, so it contains $I+(a)=(I,a)$. Conversely, every ideal containing $a$ also contains $(a)$, so the smallest ideal containing $I$ and $a$ also contains $I$ and $(a)$. Therefore $(I,a)$ contains $(I\cup(a))$.

Hence $I+(a)=(I,a)=(I\cup(a))$.